# Heap buffer overflow--is this a false positive of address sanitizer?

Tags: c, address-sanitizer, libfuzzer

I have the following simple program

```
void copy(const int16_t *buffer) {
    int16_t *b;
    memcpy(b,buffer,2);
    return ;
}


int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const int16_t *buffer) {
  copy(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

which I compile with clang (v9) using the address sanitizer and fuzzer flags as follows

```
clang -fsanitize=address,fuzzer -g test5.c
```

When I run the resulted executable the fuzzer finds a heap-buffer overflow due to an invalid read--in particular while trying to copy the second byte in memcpy.

I cannot really understand why this is an error. Any explanations? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput` is called? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why `2` and not `sizeof(int16_t)` to be clear what that number means?

Comment: @tadman Neither is making much sense.

Comment: Also shouldn't this be `memcpy(&b, &buffer, sizeof(b))`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm struggling to figure out what this code is even trying to do. If it's just copying a pointer then `memcpy` is severely complicating something simple.

Comment: Exactly. Your proposition would be plausible if `buffer` is `int16_t` and not a pointer...

Comment: Normally copy functions of this sort take a length argument to know how big the buffer is.

Comment: `b` is not assigned a value prior to calling `memcpy(b,buffer,2);`, of course the code is wonky.

Answer (score 3):

As **b** is not initialized when you **memcpy** to it, you are invoking undefined behavior.  Literally, "where do you want to copy that data to?"

The sanitizer is correct, and doing you a big favor by pointing that issue out.

What is that copy function intended to do?

Comment: Well If you are lucky, you get a SEGV.  If you are not lucky, you get silent corruption.

Comment: my very bad, I don't know how I saw `int64_t b; memcpy(&b)`. I will delete the comments